# MessageBodyWriter not found for media type REST API

Tags: java, mysql, rest, tomcat, jersey-2.0

Dears,

When trying to read from database i get following errors. Any idea how this could be resolved? I use Tomcat

```
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not 
found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.Vector, 
genericType=java.util.List<xxxxx>.

javax.servlet.ServletException: 
org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.MessageBodyProviderNotFoundException: MessageBodyWriter not 
found for media type=application/json, type=class java.util.Vector, 
genericType=java.util.List<xxxxx>.
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:333)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:372)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:335)
org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:218)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change Vector to List

OR

1. Implement MessageBodyWriter & MessageBodyReader.
2. Add @Provider annotation on both classes.

That should works.